# How should I parse dateTime for Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm pulling data from a csv where date(YYYYMMDD) and time (HHmm) are two of the columns. I already have a working parser that spits out array data points in [x, y] form. I just don't know how to parse my datetime (to use as the x-value) so Highcharts accepts it as a datetime. Just passing it in as one long number (YYYYMMDDHHmm) gives me a graph where all million points happen with a couple days in May...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options depending on how is your data:

**1) Set the correct data type as category**

The [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) states:

> The type of axis. Can be one of linear, logarithmic, **datetime** or category. **In a datetime axis, the numbers are given in milliseconds, and tick marks are placed on appropriate values like full hours or days**. In a category axis, the point names of the chart's series are used for categories, if not a categories array is defined.

To use it you would need your data in a millisecond format like:

```
[[1526688000000, 100], [1526774400000, 150], [1526860800000, 200]]
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7kL4ccL/

Then to format your datetime, you can check [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) in the documentation.

**2) Keeping the labels that way and provide a custom formatter**

To do so you must set your [`xAxis.categories.type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) to `category` for Highcharts to use your point names as categories and then provide a custom [`xAxis.labels.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) that transforms your string into whatever you want.

Example:

```
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          var year = this.value.substring(0, 4);
          var month = this.value.substring(4, 6);
          var day = this.value.substring(6, 8);
          return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
        }
      }
    },
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qpad3qh7/

Comment: Thanks for the help!